# AttributeError at /profile/ 'function' object has no attribute 'object

Tags: python, django

here is my views.py file but i keep getting this error, what could be the issue here.

Profile is a class in the models.py code. if you need another part of my code please ask

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            messages.success(request, f"Your account has been created! You are now able to login!")
            return redirect("login")
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def Profile(request):
    profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserUpdateForm( request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f"Your account has been updated!")
            return redirect("profile")
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.Profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,


    }
    return render(request, "users/profile.html", context)
```

Error Traceback

```
AttributeError at /profile/'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/
Django Version: 2.2.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
Exception Location: /Users/___/Desktop/project/users/views.py in profile, line 20
Python Executable:  /Users/___/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-9FFMjpiO/bin/python
```

Comment: Have you imported your `Profile` model in views ?

Comment: If profile is a class, it probably starts with uppercase char (it should be). So it's probably `Profile` not `profile`. and your method should starts with lowercase char, like `profile_view()`

Answer (score 0):

Line number first of Function `Profile`, the model `Profile` is probably not imported OR if imported using `profile`,

```py
profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

means you are referring to `profile` function not the Model itself.

So replace `profile` with `Profile`, change function name, and also import the model in your views.py, i.e.,

```py
@login_required
def profile_page(request):
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

Comment: I did from .models import Profile

Comment: and changed profile to Profile but it is still throwing up same error

Comment: Change the function name to be in  small letters. see if it works...